# Permission denied when installing ruby

Tags: ruby, centos

I am working on installing another version of `ruby` on another server which is `CentOS 6.7`  When while trying to configure `ruby` within the `tmp` directory I receive a:

`sudo: unable to execute ./configure: Permission denied`

Here is exactly what I am doing leading up to this:

```
mkdir /tmp/ruby && cd /tmp/ruby
curl --progress ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz | tar xz
cd ruby-2.1.2
./configure --disable-install-rdoc <!-- here is were we fail with permission denied
```

I am currently logged in as `root`.  I have played around with changing my file permissions and that did not seem to help at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you consider using `rvm` (http://rvm.io)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this link](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/604) it appears `/tmp` is mounted as read-only.

Open `/etc/fstab`, find the line that mounts your `/tmp` dir, and remove the `noexec` flag. Then remount the filesystem (or simply restart your system).

As a side note, you will also want to avoid running `./configure` and `make` as root user. Only when it comes to run `make install` should you run as root.

Comment: Martin thanks for getting back - When I view the `/etc/fstab`  all I see are 2 lines: `none    /dev/pts        devpts  rw,gid=5,mode=620       0       0
none    /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults                0       0`  - Should I just try to restart my system?

Comment: Also per your note - I am logged in as root but without doing sudo, is that not substantial enough?

Comment: the purpose of `sudo` is to temporarily make you `root` for the duration of the command. So it's essentially one and the same.

Comment: Okay gotcha - that makes sense.  What about the 2 lines that I see within the `fstab`?

Comment: Do you see the `noexec` option when running `mount |  grep tmp`?

Comment: Yes for both: `/dev/simfs on /tmp type simfs (rw,noexec,relatime)
/dev/simfs on /var/tmp type simfs (rw,noexec,relatime)
`

Comment: ok you should be able to copy those exact two lines into your `fstab` (sans the `noexec` part), reboot your system and it should work.

Comment: Martin I am a little rusty with this.  currently one line looks like this: `none    /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults                0       0
` How can I add the other two lines into this?

Comment: Ah my mistake - look into `/etc/mtab` and copy the two lines corresponding to `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` from that file into `/etc/fstab`. They are in the same format.

Comment: Oh okay so now I see `/dev/simfs /tmp simfs rw,noexec,relatime 0 0
/dev/simfs /var/tmp simfs rw,noexec,relatime 0 0`

Comment: So okay I see how I simply just need to remove the `noexec` section for those two lines - question for you, when you are dealing with a read only file how do I override that so I can write - I try using ! but that does not help

Comment: make sure you copy those lines into your fstab though. As for the read-only file, you would need to play around with `chmod` which alters the file's read/write/execute permissions. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-readonly-file-permission-in-linux-unix/

Comment: Could you send me an example of how it looks in your fstab?